# Compatibility of group structure and topological structure for topological groups

Tags: definition, topological-groups

I am fairly new to the concept of topological groups, and would like to understand the underlying idea. My question is about the compatibility between the two structures. The definition of a topological group requires that the topology on $G$ makes the multiplication and inversion maps continuous. However, I am wondering if there is an example of a topological group that does not have some topology a priori.

All the examples I know (i.e. $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{R^*}$, $\textrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, etc.) already have a topological structure, and I would like to know how the group structure affects what topologies are possible on $G$. For example, if we are given an arbitrary group $G$, and we would like to show it is a topological group, the only way I know how for now is via the definition. This seems like circular reasoning to me because it requires that we know what open subsets of $G$ are, and in order to do so we must define a topology on $G$. But to define a topology on $G$ we need to check that it makes the multiplication and inversion maps continuous, and so on...

More importantly, I have studied these objects in very separate settings (group/ring/field theory, and now topology) and I was wondering if there is a good way to unite common ideas. For now, I am having a tough time using my intuition from algebra to apply to questions regarding the topological structure of groups. I tried defining a topology on $D_6$ but got lost because of the above.

Comment: I think that you first need a group that is also a topological space and then you ask yourself the question: is it a topological group? And for this you check properties. A question like : is a given group $G$ a topological group? Well, we can always equip $G$ with the discrete topology and get a trivial topological group. I think that this question is more like: is there any interesting topology we can give $G$ that makes it a topological group?

Comment: A topological group by definition comes equipped both with a group structure and a topology. Your question can perhaps be summarized as "Does every group have a topological group structure?" Trivially, the answer is yes because you can give the group the discrete topology. (If you want a Hausdorff space, this is the best you can do for finite groups.)

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but the space of continuous functions in a closed interval is a group under addition and different topologies in it may be defined using different norms (the $\sup$ norm, the $L^1$ norm, etc.). You can check that addition and scalar multiplication by $-1$ are continuous using properties of norms.

Comment: @Shoutre, that is what I mean by "not having a topology a priori". Are you saying that the only context we should think about topological groups are those in which $G$ is \emph{both} a group and a topological space? I guess my question can be phrased as, what comes first the group or the topology (or is it both)?

Comment: Yeah, Wikipedia goes: "In mathematics, a topological group is a group G together with a topology on G such that ... ". But the question "is a group $G$" a topological group?" makes sense in a way because it can be viewed as asking if there is a non-trivial topology which makes $G$ a topological group. (non-trivial because, like Grumpy Parsnip and me said, discrete topology always turns a group $G$ in a topological group). Similar question is made in algebra when we ask if a set $S$ is a group, but we really mean "is there a binary operation in $S$ that makes it a group?"

Comment: That was a great analogy.

Comment: Also, I think that you should maybe stick to your known examples for now and study more theorical stuff about these topological groups before exploring every possible topology that could make a group $G$ a topological group, but it is just my opinion. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an exercise: suppose $G$ is a finite group. Show that picking a topology on it making it a topological group is equivalent to picking a normal subgroup $N$ of it, which is the closure of the identity in the topology (and this completely determines the topology). In particular, the only Hausdorff topology on $G$ making it a topological group is the discrete topology.

> This seems like circular reasoning to me because it requires that we know what open subsets of $G$ are, and in order to do so we must define a topology on $G$. But to define a topology on $G$ we need to check that it makes the multiplication and inversion maps continuous, and so on...

There's nothing circular here. First you define a topology and then you define a group structure. Then you can check whether they're compatible. Sometimes the answer is yes and sometimes the answer is no.